# Proper Delimiter for Batch Loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=string"

set /P q="How many subdirectories would you like to add in each folder? "

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %q%) do (
    set /P c="What is the name of subdirectory %%x? "
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=\n" %%d IN (list.txt) DO md "%%d\!c!"
 )
```

Creates folders based on a list file and adds subdirectories to each of the folders based on user input. The subdirectories creat correctly, but the list of names has some funky behavior around the delimiter. Here is a hypothetical list:

```
7 Jonathon, Hasselhoff B
7 Dean, Granger P
7 Dean, Jimmy C
7 Norris, Chuck J
7 Chan, Jackie S
```

Running this list through the code above produces the following folder names:

```
7 Jo
7 Dea
7 Norris, Chuck J
7 Cha
```

If I change the code so that `delims="` then this works as intended. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Well, you told it to treat `n` as a delimiter.

Comment: Ah - I thought I would get /n to be "newline." <return> and <enter> didn't work either. What is the proper notation for a carriage return delimiter in batch?

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%d  in.....`

Comment: Putting the closing quote after the equals symbol tells the FOR command to not use any delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, just don't include a `delims` at all. Whitespace including newlines is automatically treated as delimiters.

Comment: Don't mix the column delimiter (default `<tab>` and `<space>`, can be changed with `delim=`) with the line/loop delimiter (always `<newline>`)

Comment: This last comment nailed my sticking point - noting that the column delimiter and the line/loop delimiter are different. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest following batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:GetFolderCount
set "FolderCount="
set /P "FolderCount=How many subdirectories would you like to add in each folder? "
rem Has the user entered anything at all?
if not defined FolderCount goto GetFolderCount
rem Has the user entered a string not consisting only of digits?
for /F delims^=0123456789^ eol^= %%I in ("!FolderCount!") do goto GetFolderCount
rem Has the user entered a positive integer too large for Windows command
rem processor or being interpreted octal by cmd.exe because of leading zeros?
set /A TempCount=FolderCount
if not %TempCount% == %FolderCount% goto GetFolderCount
set "TempCount="

if not %FolderCount% == 0 (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%FolderCount%) do (
        set "FolderName="
        set /P "FolderName=What is the name of subdirectory %%I? "
        if defined FolderName for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in (list.txt) do md "%%~J\!FolderName!"
    )
)

endlocal
```

The batch file does not trust that the user enters always correct a positive integer number. Therefore the batch file first deletes the environment variable `FolderCount`.

Next it prompts the batch file user for the number of subdirectories. `FolderCount` is still not defined if the user just hits <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> resulting in prompting the user once again. It would be also possible to define `FolderCount` with a value like `1` before prompting the user to have a default which the user can use by just hitting key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The user has the freedom to enter intentionally or by mistake any string, not just a positive integer number as expected by the batch file. Therefore is verified next that the entered string consists really only of digits.

**FOR** on using option `/F` ignores empty strings (not possible anymore) and strings starting with `;`. An entered string starting with a semicolon should be interpreted as wrong input which is the reason for redefining the default `eol=;` to just `eol=` to define no end of line character and so not ignoring the string independent on what is the first character.

**FOR** splits up the string into substrings (tokens) using by default normal space and horizontal tab character as delimiters for the substrings and assigns just first substring to the specified loop variable `I`. This string splitting behavior is modified by specifying with `delims=0123456789` all digits as delimiters. The **FOR** loop does not execute the command **GOTO** if the user entered string consists only of digits as in this case nothing can be assigned to loop variable `I`. But the command **GOTO** is executed by **FOR** if there is any other character in user entered string as in this case something is assigned to the loop variable.

The alternate, not double quoted method is used to define the list of delimiters and and no end of line character which requires that the two equal signs and the space character between the two options are escaped with character caret `^` so that the entire options string is interpreted as one argument string as required by **FOR** syntax.

After passing this check the user entered string consists definitely only of digits.

But it can have leading zeros resulting in interpreting the number octal or the number is too large like `439871023842`. For that reason the user entered string is assigned to another environment variable with using an arithmetic expression which results in converting the user entered string to a 32-bit signed integer with value range `0` to `2147483647` in this case because of `-` at beginning is not possible anymore. The resulting integer is next converted back to a string which is assigned to environment variable `TempCount`. So if the string assigned to `TempCount` is not equal the string assigned to `FolderCount`, the user entered value does not fulfill the requirement of being a positive 32-bit decimal integer value.

What is still possible is that the user entered `0` for number of subdirectories in which case the next block is not executed at all as nothing to do according to user's input.

The environment variable `FolderName` is always deleted before the user is prompted in the loop for folder name. So the user has always to enter a folder name or nothing is done. The user can use key <kbd>UP</kbd> one or more times if a previous entered name for the subdirectory should be used once more.

The subdirectories are created as expected on user entered a non-empty string being valid for a folder name in each subdirectory as defined in the file `list.txt` in current directory.

The **FOR** command with option `/F` to read the lines from file `list.txt` is modified with the options `eol=|` and `delims=`, this time specified in a double quoted argument string, with not ignoring lines starting with a semicolon and not splitting up each line into substrings because of specifying an empty list of delimiters. The vertical bar is used as replacement for `;` because a folder name can't contain a vertical bar while a semicolon at beginning of a folder name is possible.

So you have defined with `delims=\n` to split the lines on backslash or letter `n` while optional argument string ending with `delims=` defines an empty list of delimiters resulting in turning off string/line splitting behavior completely and getting assigned to the specified loop variable `J` always the entire, non-empty line as read from list file if not starting with a vertical bar.

**Note:** Directory names in `list.txt` containing one or more exclamation marks are not processed correct because of enabled delayed environment variable expansion. But it looks like this is no problem here.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`